# SQL Server : self-maintained partition view issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, partitioning

I built a script some time ago to create the view and tables requires to create a structured view.
The free version of SQL Server doesn't support partitioned views so I had to build a procedure that would run nightly, created the tables and populate the data into each one based on the current data, going back in several groups of months, 6, 6-12, 12-18 etc as the data it would hold was too large to query in the live system.

Below you will see a key point in the script that split up the dates to create the tables for each partition to be used as a views source.

The fault has occurred today where it actually falls over due to the fact 6 months from today in Feb 29th, a date that simply does not exist this year!

My question comes down to this, can anyone suggest a correction to the below to handle dates that don't exist, whilst maintaining the separate date ranges and without missing dates so that any and all data can still be inserted into the view correctly. This is a tough one.

```
SET @splitcount = 8

DECLARE @counter as tinyint = 1, @monthcount as tinyint, 
        @filter as nvarchar (200 ), @droptext as nvarchar(80)

WHILE @counter <= @splitcount
BEGIN
    SET @monthcount = @counter * 6
          SET @checkdate = DATEADD( month, -@monthcount , getdate ())

    SET @filter = CASE WHEN @monthcount = 6 THEN 'requesteddatetime >= CAST('''+ CONVERT (varchar ( 12), @checkdate , 112) + ''' as DATETIME) AND requesteddatetime < CAST('''+ @7days+ ''' AS DATETIME)' ELSE 'requesteddatetime >= CAST(''' +CONVERT (varchar ( 12), @checkdate , 112 )+ ''' as DATETIME) AND requesteddatetime < CAST('''+ CONVERT( varchar( 12 ), DATEADD ( month , 6, @checkdate), 112 ) + ''' AS DATETIME)'  END
    IF @counter = @splitcount
           BEGIN
                  SET @filter = 'requesteddatetime < CAST('''+CONVERT (varchar( 12), DATEADD(month , 6 , @checkdate ), 112 ) + ''' AS DATETIME)'
           END

    SET @droptext = 'DROP TABLE dbo.CustomAudit' + CAST ( @monthcount as nvarchar (50 ))+ 'Months'
    IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.CustomAudit' +CAST ( @monthcount as nvarchar( 50))+'Months' , 'U' ) IS NOT NULL
           EXEC sp_executesql @droptext

    SET @sql = 'CREATE Table CustomAudit'+ CAST ( @monthcount as nvarchar (50 ))+'Months (
            layoutid bigint ,
            displayemployeeid nvarchar (50) NULL,
            forename nvarchar (50) COLLATE database_default ,
            surname nvarchar (50) COLLATE database_default ,
            datatablabel nvarchar (100) NOT NULL,
            requesteddatetime datetime NOT NULL CHECK (' + @filter+'),
            username nvarchar (50) COLLATE database_default ,
            updatelevel nvarchar (50) COLLATE database_default ,
            updatetype nvarchar (50) COLLATE database_default ,
            field nvarchar (100) COLLATE database_default ,
            CurrentValue nvarchar (800) COLLATE database_default ,
            Value nvarchar (800) COLLATE database_default ,
            authorised nvarchar (50) COLLATE database_default ,
            authoriserdatetime datetime ,
            authemployeedesc nvarchar (200),
            recruitment bit,
                       [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT PK_CustomAudit' +CAST ( @monthcount as nvarchar( 50))+'Months PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (surname, forename,requesteddatetime, ID)
   )

          CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_' + CAST ( @monthcount as nvarchar( 50 ))+'Months_ID ON CustomAudit'+ CAST ( @monthcount as nvarchar(50 ))+'Months (displayemployeeid)
          CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_' + CAST ( @monthcount as nvarchar( 50 ))+'Months_Label ON CustomAudit'+ CAST ( @monthcount as nvarchar(50 ))+'Months (datatablabel)'
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql
        PRINT 'dbo.CustomAudit' +CAST ( @monthcount as nvarchar( 50))+'Months Created'
        PRINT 'Filter: ' + @filter

   SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```